# Problem using pg_dump in Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to copy a remote database onto my local machine using the following command

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin>pg_dump -h remote_server -U remote_user_name -c database_name | psql -a -h localhost -d local_database -U local_user_name
```

While doing so, it encounters an error saying data for the column not found.

Based on information from [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/73642/postgresql-db-restoring-from-dump-fails) I would guess that presence of characters like new line, ellipsis, right arrow in character varying column just before the column on which it errors out could be one of the reason.

So what could I do to circumvent this problem? One option is I rewrite that column, but there could many such data rows and I am not fond of this band aid type solution. I am a database noob so not sure which other documentations should I look into.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing this in two steps, first writing the `pg_dump` output into a file and then feeding it to `psql`?  And an actual error message (which may even show the row number it originates from) would be more than handy.

Comment: @dezso The second part of the command psql has '-a' option turned on which spits the line number on terminal where it failed. Looking at the row of the table where it encountered did show me that the column previous to one pointed as missing data did had some special characters(like newline, ellipsis(...), right arrow(->)). Is there anything more that I can do to get precise diagnosis?

Comment: Even Windows can't be broken enough that a pipe isn't 8-bit clean, surely. Please show the exact error. Also, I second dezso: Test it in two steps to see if that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using plain text dump and that's why it break on those characters. 
Try with custom format and use pg_restore for restoring the database.

[check this tutorial](http://www.commandprompt.com/blogs/joshua_drake/2010/07/a_better_backup_with_postgresql_using_pg_dump/)

Be aware that you need to copy also user rights or recreate them on new machine related with the database.